# How to use intellisense with watir and watir-webdriver?

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver, rubymine

I use RubyMine 5.4

I want to use Internet Explorer.

Here are the first lines in a file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
#require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'test/unit'

URL = 'http://google.com/'

class TestGoogle < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new
  end
...
end
```

Here is my problem. I have squiggly lines under "Watir" and "Browser" in the following line:

```
@browser = Watir::Browser.new
```

As a result, I can't use intellisense for these words, and many other words.

I can remove the squiggly lines, and use intellisense, if I uncomment

```
#require 'watir-webdriver'
```

But I've been told that I cannot require both 'watir' and 'watir-webdriver'in the same file.

To add to my confusion, in the following site:

```
http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/
```

On the first page, I see the lines:

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
```

I would be grateful for any advice. At my stage of learning, I really need the inellisense.

Comment: When you say you want to use IE, do you mean you want to only use IE? If you are using other browsers as well, do you care which IE implementation (ie classic vs webdriver) you use?

Comment: @justin. IE is the only browser supported by the customer. But if something fails in IE, I often try a quick test with Chrome or FF to help the troubleshooting.

Comment: Did you have preference/requirement for whether you use Watir-Classic vs the Watir-Webdriver implementation for IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using RubyMine as well and when I copy pasted your code, I didn't see any problem.

I always use 'watir-webdriver', which interanlly uses selenium webdriver (supports different browsers) instead of 'watir'.

Goto Tools -> Show Gem Environment and check whether you have 'watir-webdriver' listed.

If it is not listed there then goto Tools -> Terminal and install the watir-webdriver gem.

Refresh the project or restart the IDE to see the changes.

Hope it helps for you.